# Маппинг процессов в Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

А подскажите как происходит маппинг процессов на воркеры в кассандре?
Есть задача заменить столбец в таблице с записями None на значения 1. Я же правильно понимаю, что cql не позволяет сделать UPDATE пачке значений через итератор. Как правильно это делать?

Comment: btw, мы открыли раздел для вопросов на русском на нашем форуме посвященном Кассандре: https://community.datastax.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Есть два подхода:

1. Изменить приложение, так чтобы оно вместо None возвращало 1
2. Сделать изменение путем сканирования всей таблицы, извлечения всех значений primary key, и изменение столбца для каждой из строк

Сканирование всей таблицы можно сделать:

1. с помощью спарка и [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/) - это наверное самый удобный способ, но требует Spark, хотя можно гонять и в локальном режиме;
2. программно, но тут надо правильно выполнить сканирование, так чтобы все token ranges были правильно и эффективно обработаны. У меня есть [пример на яве](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java), который в принципе делает то что и спарк для эффективного сканирования таблицы;
3. Выгрузить необходимые колонки (primary key + изменяемая колонка) с помощью [DataStax DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html), с помощью утилит, типа sed/... произвести изменения, и загрузить данные обратно.

Comment: 2. вариант точно не мой, выйдет слишком медленно
А что касается распределения воркеров и маппинга, как это делается?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю терминов - что такое воркер ?